# 'streamlit-card' FileNotFoundError when running Streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit, python-3.12

I'm having trouble using my Streamlit app because of a problem with the **[streamlit-card](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-card/)** package. This is the error message I'm seeing:

```
2023-12-04 11:07:31.911 ComponentRequestHandler: GET /home/esoftdev1/bulkApi-deshboard/bulkapi-deshboard-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/streamlit_card/frontend/build/null read error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/esoftdev1/bulkApi-deshboard/bulkapi-deshboard-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/streamlit/web/server/component_request_handler.py", line 55, in get
    with open(abspath, "rb") as file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/esoftdev1/bulkApi-deshboard/bulkapi-deshboard-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/streamlit_card/frontend/build/null'
```

**- Code I used**

```
from streamlit_card import card

count_yesterday = run_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE op_status = 9000 AND DATE(creation_datetime) = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day');")

yesterday = count_yesterday[0][0]
print(yesterday) #464

res = card(
             text="Yesterday's Count",
             title=yesterday,
             styles={
                 "card": {
                     "width": "300px",
                     "height": "300px",
                    "border-radius": "10px",
                     "background-color": "RGB(128, 61, 245)",
                     "box-shadow": "0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                 },
                 "text": {
                    "font-family": "Times New Roman",
                 },
             },
         )
```

it shows
[image]

**- Environment:**
Python version: 3.12.0, Streamlit version: 1.29.0, streamlit-card version: 0.0.61

**- Directory Structure:**

```
/home/esoftdev1/bulkApi-deshboard/bulkapi-deshboard-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/streamlit_card/frontend/build
```

1. static (directory),
2. service-worker.js,
3. precache-manifest.6b8328ae49df780207c52d2ceeaeadd9.js,
4. index.html,
5. bootstrap.min.css.map,
6. bootstrap.min.css,
7. asset-manifest.json

I have uninstalled streamlit-card using the command `python3.12 -m pip uninstall streamlit-card`, reinstalled streamlit-card using the command `python3.12 -m pip install streamlit-card` and upgraded streamlit-card using the command `python3.12 -m pip install streamlit-card --upgrade`. I have cleared the browser cache.

Comment: Please include your code.  It isn't clear where this ```null``` is coming from.

Comment: What is ```yesterday```?  Is it ```null```?

Comment: no. it is a number.

Comment: Please explain what you're doing.  Why are you using streamlit-card?  Aren't you supposed to be including the 'image'?

Comment: I want to show the count of my records as a card in my app. It works well, but I see an error in my terminal. @ewokx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a default image on the card, for some reason, the package does not allow the image to be optional. So using a sample image would be the best way.

Sample implementation:

```
from streamlit_card import card

count_yesterday = run_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE op_status = 9000 AND DATE(creation_datetime) = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day');")

yesterday = count_yesterday[0][0]
print(yesterday) #464

res = card(
             text="Yesterday's Count",
             title=yesterday,
             styles={
                 "card": {
                     "width": "300px",
                     "height": "300px",
                    "border-radius": "10px",
                     "background-color": "RGB(128, 61, 245)",
                     "box-shadow": "0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                 },
                 "text": {
                    "font-family": "Times New Roman",
                 },
             },
             image="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/48/Blank.JPG"
         )
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, the background image is not optional, this throws the error.

There's an open issue here: https://github.com/gamcoh/st-card/issues/25